# ScrollView still scrolling with hidden contents

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a ScrollView with a RelativeView beneath it. Within that RelativeView, there are 3 views in it. 2 of those 3 are initially hidden.

[image]

Even though on my phone the scroller_rel doesn't take up the whole screen, I can still scroll through as if scroller_rel2 and scroller_rel3 are there and not hidden.

Programmatically I will decide if scroller_rel2 and scroller_rel3 are hidden or visible, and I'm wondering how to also then decide if we should be able to scroll or not.

The easy way to ask this question is: How can I programmatically tell ScrollView  the height of the visible contents, so that if the contents are not larger than the container, we disable scrolling, and if say 2 of the 3 are showing, how can we then enable scrolling only to the bottom of scroller_rel2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're having this problem is because setting the view to be `View.INVISIBLE` does just that, but it still takes up space in your layout, so that's why you can still scroll. What you should be using is `View.GONE`, this actually sets the view to be invisible and it removes it from the layout. Check out the documentation here:

[GONE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE)

[INVISIBLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE)